# Reference request: Lifting problem for smooth curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

In FGA it was proved that smooth curve over field k can be lift to complete local ring with residue field k, but I think it’s unreadable for me. So are there more modern introduction for this problem and related ones?

Comment: What is FGA ?...

Comment: @JeanMarie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fondements_de_la_G%C3%A9ometrie_Alg%C3%A9brique

Comment: If $X$ is a variety over $k$ and $R=k[[t]]$, then $X\times_k k[[t]]$ is a lift. (It is the "trivial" lift in some sense.) You are probably looking for a less trivial statement which you can find in (presumably) any book on deformation theory. Have a look at Hartshorne's book and/or Sernesi's book.

Comment: Since it might be a bit unclear: $X\times_k k[[t]]$ is short for $X\times_{\mathrm{Spec} \ k} \mathrm{Spec} \ k[[t]]$.

Comment: @Ariyan Javanpeykar Thanks ; I appreciate ; my impression is that the author of the question is a mute person...